# scrape under "show more"

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all the objects with the same tag from a specific site (Google Scholar) with BeautifulSoup, but it doesn't scrap the object under the "show more" at the end of the page. How can I fix it?

Here's an example of my code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1253 -*-
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
webpage=urlopen('http://scholar.google.gr/citations?user=FwuKA4UAAAAJ&hl=el')
soup=BeautifulSoup(webpage)
for t in soup.findAll('a',{"class":"gsc_a_at"}):
      print t.text
```

Comment: That content is probably produced by JS, hence you need to run a scraper that renders the JS as well. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028775/tried-python-beautifulsoup-and-phantom-js-still-cant-scrape-websites/22030553#22030553) from me that gives you an idea how you can load the page with JS. After that, you need to run the function that displays more content, and then scrape the results.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885290/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-pyqt) answer may help you to run javascript functions using PyQT.

Comment: thank you, but which function displays more content?

Comment: I don't know, you have to inspect the source of the page you are scraping, and see what function is called when you click the "Show more" button.

Comment: i read the source of the page but i didn't find any <script> tag. Is that mean that the page doesn't use JS ? or can i find it out with another way?(sorry but i am beginner)

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass pagination parameters to the request url.

`cstart` - Parameter defines the result offset. It skips the given number of results. It's used for pagination. (e.g., 0 (default) is the first page of results, 20 is the 2nd page of results, 40 is the 3rd page of results, etc.).

`pagesize` - Parameter defines the number of results to return. (e.g., 20 (default) returns 20 results, 40 returns 40 results, etc.). Maximum number of results to return is 100.

You could also use a third party solution like SerpApi to do this for you. It's a paid API with a free trial.

Example python code (available in other libraries also) to retrieve the second page of results:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google_scholar_author",
  "hl": "en",
  "author_id": "FwuKA4UAAAAJ",
  "start": "20",
  "api_key": "secret_api_key"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
```

Example JSON output:

```json
"articles": [
  {
    "title": "MuseumScrabble: Design of a mobile game for children’s interaction with a digitally augmented cultural space",
    "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=FwuKA4UAAAAJ&cstart=20&citation_for_view=FwuKA4UAAAAJ:RHpTSmoSYBkC",
    "citation_id": "FwuKA4UAAAAJ:RHpTSmoSYBkC",
    "authors": "C Sintoris, A Stoica, I Papadimitriou, N Yiannoutsou, V Komis, N Avouris",
    "publication": "Social and organizational impacts of emerging mobile devices: Evaluating use …, 2012",
    "cited_by": {
      "value": 69,
      "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=6286720977869955347",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=6286720977869955347&engine=google_scholar&hl=en",
      "cites_id": "6286720977869955347"
    },
    "year": "2012"
  },
  {
    "title": "The effective combination of hybrid usability methods in evaluating educational applications of ICT: Issues and challenges",
    "link": "https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=FwuKA4UAAAAJ&cstart=20&citation_for_view=FwuKA4UAAAAJ:hqOjcs7Dif8C",
    "citation_id": "FwuKA4UAAAAJ:hqOjcs7Dif8C",
    "authors": "N Tselios, N Avouris, V Komis",
    "publication": "Education and Information Technologies 13 (1), 55-76, 2008",
    "cited_by": {
      "value": 68,
      "link": "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cites=1046912849634390721",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?cites=1046912849634390721&engine=google_scholar&hl=en",
      "cites_id": "1046912849634390721"
    },
    "year": "2008"
  },
  ...
```

Check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-author-api) for more details.

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, try F12 --> Network, select 'Preserve log' and disable cache.
Now hit the show more button.

Check the GET/POST request being sent. You will know what to do next.