# Why the "linkClicked(const QUrl&)" signal does not capture a QUrl for the left mouse button?

Tags: python, pyqt

First, I'd like to make it clear that this strange behavior does not apply to every website.

Here's the code from my [web browser](https://github.com/EricsonWillians/Open-Browser):

```
def compose_tab(self, index):
    self.tabs[index].append(QtWebKit.QWebView())
    self.tabs[index][0].setLayout(self.tabs[index][1])
    self.tabs[index][1].addWidget(self.tabs[index][2])
    self.tabs[index][2].connect(self.tabs[index][2], QtCore.SIGNAL("linkClicked(const QUrl&)"), self.update_link)
    # to be written...
    self.tabs[index][2].connect(self.tabs[index][2], QtCore.SIGNAL("OPEN_IN_NEW_TAB"), lambda: [
        # self.add_tab(len(self.tabs)-1),
        None,
        None
    ])
    self.tabs[index][2].load(QtCore.QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
    self.url_field.setText("http://www.google.com")
    self.tabs[index][2].page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(QtWebKit.QWebPage.DelegateAllLinks)
    self.tabs[self.tab_stack.currentIndex()][2].loadProgress.connect(lambda: self.tab_stack.setTabText(
        self.tab_stack.currentIndex(), 
        "Loading..."
    ))
    try:
        self.tabs[self.tab_stack.currentIndex()][2].loadFinished.connect(lambda: self.tab_stack.setTabText(
            self.tab_stack.currentIndex(), 
            self.tabs[self.tab_stack.currentIndex()][2].page().mainFrame().findFirstElement("title").toPlainText()
        ))
    except NameError as e:
        pass
    self.current_links.insert(index, self.url_field.text())
    self.tabs[index][2].show()
```

As you can see, each tab has a QWebView on it connected with the update_link method, which is this one:

```
def update_link(self, url):
    self.url_field.setText(url.toString())
    self.current_links[self.tab_stack.currentIndex()] = url.toString()
    self.tabs[self.tab_stack.currentIndex()][2].load(url)
```

So each time a link is clicked, the URL field gets updated with the QUrl that is passed to the method. It works just fine in websites like wikipedia, but it does not work well on youtube (For example). [As one can read from the docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebpage.html#linkClicked), the signal may not be emitted if Javascript is involved. That's "ok", but there's a problem:

The signal **does** get emitted when I click on the link with the middle mouse button (Which makes no sense!).

So, if I access a video on youtube with the first mouse button, the URL field does not get updated as no QUrl gets passed to the update_link method, but if I click with the middle mouse button, the URL field gets updated normally. This is extremely puzzling, since I can't "override" a signal and change this behavior.

Could anyone run my browser and check the behavior? (Since reproducing it would require a considerable amount of work).

EDIT:

The [urlChanged signal](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebview.html#urlChanged) also does not pass the QUrl when clicked with the left mouse button on youtube videos. Waiting for loadFinished is also useless.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your question directly, but based on this and your previous question I suspect you're making things more difficult for yourself than you need to. `QWebView` handles the navigation of URLs within the view (including with JavaScript) automatically so you do not need to handle mouse events or links directly.

When a link is clicked in the view, the next page will automatically open, and `QWebView` will fire an `urlChanged` signal. If you want to keep the URL bar in sync, you can connect to this signal and simply update the URL bar text, for example:

```
webview.urlChanged.connect(<custom slot function>)
```

The slot function will receive a `QUrl` representing the URL of the new page, which you can convert to a string:

```
def url_changed(self, q):
   <your-urlbar-obj>.setText(q.toString())
```

Comment: Very interesting, I did not know about urlChanged. I've tested with it, but on Youtube the URL field stays in "www.youtube.com" forever as I access the videos. This is a problem because I'm trying to implement bookmarks (And I need the link of each video to be associated with its title in a dict). Somewhere in this, there's a problem with PyQt4.

Comment: @EricsonWillians That's strange, when I do it here it works fine. I've post the source for a demo tabbed browser I put together here for comparison http://gist.github.com/mfitzp/d6fa26865e2beeb4f9e9a5701f33091a

Comment: Well, you use PyQt5 and I use PyQt4, so perhaps that's the problem. I'll update mine and check if it works.

Comment: @EricsonWillians I've just tested it with PyQt4 (adjusting the imports) and I can replicate the issue on youtube.com — very strange! I would chalk this one up as a bug.

Comment: @EricsonWillians If you're comfortable getting hacky you might get somewhere using `.loadFinished` and executing JavaScript in the window.

Comment: I can't get this thing to work. No matter what I do, PyQt4 does not give that link to me, I'm trying for 3 days now. I've installed PyQt5 and I got opengl errors on windows when using the "webkit", so I've returned to PyQt4. Do you have any idea on how I could get that "javascript link" with .loadFinished? At this moment, I'm really feeling comfortable getting hacky.

Comment: @EricsonWillians I would really recommend perservering to PyQt5 to work. If you're using Python 2.7 this is a good route: http://blog.abstractfactory.io/pyqt5-1-1-for-python-2-7/

Comment: @EricsonWillians for the `.loadFinished` idea you would need to connect to that and then use `.evaluateJavascript` in the window to catch navigation events from Javascript. You can send data back out (e.g. via a signal) to your application. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885290/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-pyqt for the first steps.