# Is it possible to trigger a mousePressEvent artificially on a QWebView?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

[Due to an astronomically atrocious bug on PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366399/why-the-linkclickedconst-qurl-signal-does-not-capture-a-qurl-for-the-left-m), I need to fire a mousePressEvent artificially on a QWebView as a last breath of hope. For some obscure reason, QWebView's [linkClicked](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebview.html#linkClicked) and [urlChanged](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebview.html#urlChanged) signals do not pass a QUrl when the clicked link has Javascript involved (It does not work on Youtube videos, for example) **and** when the link was clicked with the left mouse button. The QUrl can be perfectly accessed when the link was clicked with the middle and right buttons.

```
class CQWebView(QtWebKit.QWebView): 

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if type(event) == QtGui.QMouseEvent:
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                # FIRE A QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton EVENT HERE,
                # SO THAT I CAN GET THE BLOODY LINK AFTERWARDS.
            elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
                self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("OPEN_IN_NEW_TAB")) # Example
            elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
                self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("XXX")) # Example
```

So, I literally want to "click artificially", click without clicking, just trigger the event of clicking with the middle right button on a link, so that I can catch the QUrl correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using the `QtTest` module as well.  Set an event filter on your web view and check for left click mouse events and send a middle mouse click

```
def __init__(...)
    self.ui_web_view.installEventFilter(self)

def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if obj == self.ui_web_view:
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                print 'Handled'
                QtTest.QTest.mouseClick(self.ui_web_view, QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier, event.pos())
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: I can't believe! You've just solved my problem! haha. It works just like my solution, but this one does not override linkClicked and urlChanged. Fantastic! Thank you very much! I'll rely more on QtTest now.

Comment: You might also be able to combine the solutions and use `app.sendEvent`, but send it from the event filter instead of overriding the `mousePressEvent` handler.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to click with the middle button by clicking with the left button using the [sendEvent method from QtGui.QApplication](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcoreapplication.html#sendEvent).

```
class CQWebView(QtWebKit.QWebView): 

    app = None

    def __init__(self, app):
        QtWebKit.QWebView.__init__(self)
        CQWebView.app = app

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if type(event) == QtGui.QMouseEvent:
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                CQWebView.app.sendEvent(self, QtGui.QMouseEvent(event.type(), event.pos(), QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton, event.buttons(), event.modifiers()))
            elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
                self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("linkClicked(const QUrl&)")) # Problem
            elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
                self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("XXX")) # Example
```

I just needed to pass the instance of the QApplication to the instance of the custom QWebView on instantiation:

```
def compose_tab(self, index):
        self.tabs[index].append(CQWebView(self))
```

This way, I click on the QWebView with the left mouse button and I click artificially on it with the middle button. **The problem is** that doing so I'm overriding the default behavior of the linkClicked and urlChanged signals from the QWebView. Even though I can emit these signals, I can't have access to the address of the link that was clicked, since by accessing QWebView.url() only gives me the **present** QUrl, and not the future clicked one.

**Really** frustrating.

Comment: Yeah, the `QWebView` is pretty much junk.  It's always been slow and buggy as long as I can remember.