# printing an output of javascript in a webpage using selenium and python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I was making an python program that executes a java script after loading a [webpage](https://html5.haxball.com/headless) it is a web based api where we can execute javascript commands through console of your browser (f12) ( api [documentation](https://github.com/haxball/haxball-issues/wiki/Headless-Host))

This executing gives back an array, I just want to get this output of execution (the array) to be print. the code i used is given below. the time delay of 15 seconds is used for solving an captcha which have to do manually.
 executing `getPlayerList();` command will give back you a list of players that is currently playing.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://html5.haxball.com/headless")
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("""
window.room = window.HBInit({ roomName: 'botts', maxPlayers: 16 });
""")
#the time dalay is to solve the captcha manually that appear on the browser after executing above javascript.
time.sleep(15)
print(driver.execute_script(""" 
console.log(window.getPlayerList();
"""))
```

The above program works fine, but i have to print the output of `getPlayerList();` I tried with `return` and `console log`, but that is not working for me.

Comment: where you define `getPlayerList()` ?

Comment: If I understood correctly, `getPlayerList()` is a function that's defined in the webpage you're scraping. You **can't** use functions that aren't defined within the scope of your code.

Comment: the web page i was running https://html5.haxball.com/headless it is a web based api where we can execute javascript commands through console of your browser (f12) ( api documentation https://github.com/haxball/haxball-issues/wiki/Headless-Host) .  executing getPlayerList(); command will give back you a list of players that is currently playing. getPlayerList(); is already defined in their api.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define your `getPlayerList()` function take this as example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://html5.haxball.com/headless")
driver.execute_script("""
    // window.room = window.HBInit({ roomName: 'botts', maxPlayers: 16 });

    // define the getPlayerList() functio;
    window.getPlayerList = function() {
        // here you make all the functional that you need
        return 'All players list';
    }

""")

driver.execute_script(""" 
    // now that we define our function, we can call it
    console.log(window.getPlayerList();
""")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am Agree with the @zimdero answer and the @GalAbra comment if you use Selenium.

---

But **if you have absolutely the requirement to execute the javascript function which is present in the loaded page**, you may achieve this by **use of [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro)** and [QwebView](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwebview.html) class, with something like this:

```
browser = QwebView()
browser.load(QUrl("https://html5.haxball.com/headless"))
frame = browser.page().currentFrame()
#do your stuff here
#execute js function inside the webpage
frame.evaluateJavaScript(QString("getPlayerList()"))
```

For more information, take a look on [How to call javascript function from PyQT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885290/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-pyqt)